# what is "operator T*(void)" and when it is invoked?

Tags: c++

I have 2 files:

```
/****demo.cpp****/
#include <iostream.h>
#include "gc.h"

class foo{};

int main(){
    gc<foo> x1;
    cout<<x1;
}

/*****gc.h*****/
template <class T> class gc 
{
    T* ptr;
public:
    operator T*(){}
};
```

If I don't write `operator T*(){}` then I get a lot of compiler errors.

So plz tell me what is `operator T*(void)` and when it is invoked?

Answer (score 3):

#### Regarding your Question

`operator type ()`  is a so-called cast operator. if there is a need for conversion to `type`, then that operator function is used to do the conversion.

in your example, cout uses your `operator T* ()` to convert your x1 object using a user defined implicit conversion to a pointer, which is then output by ostream's (cout is of class std::ostream) `operator<<` which takes a void* .

#### Other Problems

To help you figure out other problems, change the header file name from `iostream.h` to `iostream` . Standard C++ does not know `iostream.h` . Those files were called like that before C++ was made a Standard. Also, all C headers you use, like `math.h, stdio.h` are still valid in C++, but they are so-called backward-compatibility header files. You should include for example `cmath` and `cstdio` instead. That will put all names that are not macros in C into the `namespace std`. Instead of using `cout` , you use `std::cout` . Likewise for other identifiers too.

Comment: but how does the compiler know that this line does conversion...
i replaced this line with "operator void*(){}"...it also works.How?

thx for the comments in other problems...
thats quite enlightment...i did not know this...

Comment: what about conio.h for getch()?

Comment: conio.h is windows specific. avoid it. for your other question. The compiler cannot call operator<< with both cout and your object as arguments. Thus it looks for a standard conversion. It doesn't find one. Then it looks for a user-defined conversion, and finds your cast operator.

Answer (score 2):

operator `T*(){}`  is a [cast operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts48df3y.aspx).  You are providing a function that can be used to convert from a `gc<T>` to a `T*` ... though it should require that you actually return something, presumably `ptr` in this case.

The problem is that the compiler doesn't know how to format your gc object to the output stream.

By providing a cast from gc to foo* it is able to output the object as just a pointer value ... probably not what you want.

You likely want to define a custom overload for the << operator to dump out your class:

```
template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, const gc<T>& x)
{
    // os << .. something useful here ..
    return os;
}
```

Comment: thx...
but how does the compiler know that this line does conversion...
i replaced this line with "operator void*(){}"...it also works.
How?

Comment: The cast operator gives the compiler a way to convert a gc<T> to a T*, or in this case a void*

For the cout line the compiler has to work out which overload of operator<< it can call based on the arguments.  It doesn't know how to deal with a gc<T> directly, but it can deal with pointer types.