# What does the overload "operator X*() const" mean?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is “operator T*(void)” and when it is invoked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275169/what-is-operator-tvoid-and-when-it-is-invoked)

As we know that the following code is to overload the * and & operator

```
X& operator*() const
{
    return *this;
}

X* operator&() const
{
    return this;
}
```

but I don't know what is the following code mean? (it can pass build) it seems that it is used to get the pointer of X.

```
operator X*() const
{
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
operator X*() const
{
    return this;
}
```

`Implicit conversion operator` to type `X*`. It's user-defined conversion. Read `12.3` of standard for more information. Related [Strange way of overloading the dereference operator from a BoostCon talk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018404/strange-way-of-overloading-the-dereference-operator-from-a-boostcon-talk/12018456#12018456)

Answer (score 1):

This is a so-called *user-defined conversion*, or UDC. They allow you to specify conversions to other types via constructors or special conversion functions.

The syntax looks like this:

```
operator <some_type_here>();
```

so your particular case is a conversion operator to the type `X*`.

There are some things you should remember when coding those:

- a UDC must not be ambiguous, or it will not be called
- the compiler can only use UDC to implicitly convert a single object at a time, so chaining implicit conversions does not work:

  ```
  class A 
  {
      int x;
  public:
      operator int() { return x; };
  };

  class B 
  {
      A y;
  public:
      operator A() { return y; };
  };

  int main () 
  {
      B obj_b;
      int i = obj_b;//will fail, because it requires two implicit conversions: A->B->int
      int j = A(obj_b);//will work, because the A->B conversion is explicit, and only B->int is implicit.
  }
  ```
- A conversion function in a derived class does not hide a conversion function in the base class, unless they convert to the same type.
- When converting through a construtor, only default conversions can be used. For example:

  ```
  class A
  {
      A(){}
      A(int){}
  }
  int main()
  {
      A obj1 = 15.6;//will work, because float->int is a standart conversion
      A obj2 = "Hello world!";//will not work, you'll have to define a cunstructor that takes a string.
  }
  ```

You can find additional info [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr383.htm), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/047b2c75.aspx) or [here](http://cpppearls.blogspot.com/2007/07/implict-conversions-user-defined.html).